# Converting .skp file to .gif using Terminal in Linux

Tags: 3d, gif

Is there a way to convert .skp files from Sketchup software into GIFs?

For example, I want to download the cat.skp model here and convert it to GIF animation:

https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model/b38f00da-d90c-4b32-a588-6e07d4683260/Cat

Answer (score 0):

I think converting the files it not possible. I would export a .mp4 file from Sketchup and then convert this via `ffmpeg`.

Comment: problem is sketchup is a paid software and I don't have license for it